# The method getPreferenceManager() is undefined for the type BatteryService in android app

Tags: java, android

I am making a service so I have service class which is extended from Service. I am getting a checkbox from PreferenceScreen and based on whether it is checked or not I perform an action. To get CheckBoxPreference I use getPreferenceManager() method. But it has red underline. When I hover over it shows me this error `The method getPreferenceManager() is undefined for the type BatteryService`. When I use the same code in my main class then it works. Here is my code

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    initNotification();

    final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("cbAlarm");

    checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    if (newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        registerReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
                    } else if (newValue.toString().equals("false")) {
                        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                BatteryService.class));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Help Please

Comment: anyone who can help? I am still waiting for help

Answer (score 3):

The `getPreferencesManager()` function is not available on `Service` derived objects - only  on PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment derived objects where you likely copied the above code from, or individual Preference objects.

If you only wanted to sample the value of the checkbox preference when your service starts, use something like:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean alarm = sp.getBoolean("cbAlarm", false);    // defaulting to false
```

However, I'm guessing from your Listener code that you also want to be notified if the user changes the setting.  That would mean keeping onPreferenceChange in the PreferenceActivity/PreferenceFragment, and sending the service a message.  For that, consider something like [Android best way to communicate from an Activity to a Service / Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105883/android-best-way-to-communicate-from-an-activity-to-a-service-engine), or simply start/stop the whole service if it has nothing to do when the Alarm is off!