# Android best way to communicate from an Activity to a Service / Engine

Tags: android, android-service

I have a WallpaperEngine that needs to start an activity - a simple option menu.

I need the result of that menu selection.  What is the best way to communicate from the activity back to the service, since it has no reference to the service and I can't do startActivityForResult.

Thanks!

Comment: if the service and the activity are in the same app (and process) you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html from compat package

Comment: this worked great for me, I would mark it as an accepted answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Binders` and `ServiceConnection` to connect your `Serivce` to your `Activity`.

In your `Activity`:

```
private YourService mService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {       
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = ((YourBinder)service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, YourService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mConnection != null){
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }   
    super.onPause();
}
```

Your `Binder`:

```
public class YourBinder extends Binder {
    private WeakReference<YourService> mService;

    public YourBinder(YourService service){
        mService = new WeakReference<YourService>(service)
    }

    public YourService getService(){
        return mService.get();
    }
}
```

In your `Service`:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new YourBinder(this);
}
```

After this you can call the public methods of your `Service` from your `Activity`. Note, that the binding is asynchronous. By the time you can interact with the UI of the `Activity`, the connection is already established, but in the `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods your `Service` object will be still null probably.

Comment: Thanks, it was good learning about this method.  However onBind cannot be overriden in a wallpaper service - its a final method :(.  Maybe I will try local broadcasts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tutorial here:
http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android

What you'll be doing is binding your activity to the service which will give the activity a reference and the ability to do anything with the service. (The tutorial covers starting the service from an activity, but you don't need to do this of course)